# How do I get a handle to the UVM factory?

Tags: uvm

I'd like to get a handle to the UVM factory so as to use function such as `set_type_override_by_name()`.

Comment: An instance named `factory` is automatically created internally in UVM. You can use it directly. Directly use `factory.set_type_override_by_name ("original_type_name","override_type_name");`. Though I'll prefer your method.

Comment: I'd avoid using `set_*_override_by_name(...)` and use the strongly typed versions instead. Also, I prefer using `orig_type::type_id::set_*_override(ovr_type::get_type(), ...)`.

Comment: I'm creating a sequence based on the name of the test.  So there is no way to use the strong type.  I do get_type_name() and concatenate it with "_sequence" then do an override.

So now all my tests look like:

  `    `my_test_macro(ray_test)`
Which automatically creates and launches `ray_test_sequence`.

Comment: Sharvil111, automatically created where?  In uvm_pkg?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but this is what I found in the source code. `const uvm_factory factory = uvm_factory::get();`. `get()` method returns a singleton of factory. If singleton is not created, then it creates an object. So, I guess factory is statically initialized inside uvm_pkg itself. I am referring to [this](http://www.specman-verification.com/source_bank/uvm-1.1/src/base/uvm_factory.svh.php) file, maybe an older source code of UVM.

Comment: I did not know that was in there.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is there in UVM 1.2, but I am not sure about 1.1, though it is more likely that the same would be there in 1.1also.

Answer (score 1):

The UVM factory uses the singleton design pattern to provide a handle.  You get() a handle using the static get() method.

```
uvm_factory uvm_factory_h;
uvm_factory_h = uvm_factory::get();
uvm_factory_h.set_type_override_by_name("original_type_name","override_type_name");
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use set_type_override_by_name method, without having uvm_factory handle.

**For uvm_factory Handle -**

Still, if you want to have uvm_factory class handle ,then you can use uvm_coreservice_t class to get uvm_factory handle.

> The singleton instance of uvm_coreservice_t provides a common point
>   for all central uvm services such as uvm_factory, uvm_report_server
>   and so on.
>
> The service class provides a static <::get> which returns
>   an instance adhering to uvm_coreservice_t. The rest of the
>   set_ get_ pairs provide access to the internal uvm
>   services

To get uvm_factory handle:

```
uvm_coreservice_t cs = uvm_coreservice_t::get();                                                     
uvm_factory factory = cs.get_factory();
factory.set_type_override_by_name(original_type_name,override_type_name, replace);
```

For more information, visit http://sourceforge.net/p/uvm/code/ci/UVM_1_2_RELEASE/tree/distrib/src/base/uvm_coreservice.svh

Comment: Mostly no, as these are base classes of UVM, so there should be something similar or may be same in UVM 1.1 also.